# Dbpedia does not return full results

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Beginner in DBPedia/SPARQL/Semantic data. I ran following queries to "find out the sport for each athlete"

```
select ?athlete ?sport where 
{
   ?athlete rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete>.   #query1
   ?athlete dbpedia2:sport ?sport                             #query2
}
```

It does give results but not the full set that I am looking for. "query1" by itself returns more athletes but combined with "query2", I get a lot less resultset.

Please explain the discrepancy. Am I missing something? Whats the alternative?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query selects all athlete nodes which have *both* rdf:type and dbpedia2:sport properties. You can use `optional` clause to retrieve nodes even if some property isn't bound. For example:

```
select ?athlete ?sport where {
    ?athlete rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete>. #query1
    optional {?athlete dbpedia2:sport ?sport} #query2
}
```

Better way to get sport:

```
select ?athlete ?type where {
    ?athlete rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete>.
    optional {
        ?athlete rdf:type ?type.
        ?type rdfs:subClassOf <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It now returns Athletes even if the sport property is not bound. But my quest is to "get the sport SOMEHOW for each Athlete". From the results it seems that for an athlete, sport property may be unbound? How do I get that since Athlete -> Sport relationship is incomplete. Sport -> Athlete relationship does not exist. Regards,

Comment: In such cases you need to better explore ontology. rdfs:subClassOf Athlete describes needed information. I've added another query to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I came up with this. Please provide feedback on the query.select ?sport ?athlete where {
    ?sport rdfs:subClassOf <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Athlete>.
    ?athlete a $sport
}

Comment: That's a good one if you want to skip athletes for whom rdfs:subClass of Athlete isn't specified (3250 from 150978).

Comment: Apologies but I dont understand (3250 from 150978). This is my last question on the topic.

Comment: There's no need to apologise :). I meant that 3250 athlete records from 150978 on DBpedia have no rdfs:subClassOf Athlete specified (i.e. no details about what kind of athlete it is). So you wouldn't see corresponding rows in a result set.